# Convert Mouse position in pixels into rows and column (or PS) in Mainframe emulator

Tags: emulation, mainframe, microfocus

Need to convert mouse coordinates into PS position or row and column on mainframe emulator.

I'm using Whllapi to connect and automate mainframe emulator. I need to find a underlying field when user move mouse or click on a field at emulator screen. To identify a field on mainframe emulator i need to know row and column or PS position. I need to convert mouse position (in pixels) to emulator row and column. But there is no API in whllapi that provides such functionality.

I used whllapi api "QueryWindowCoordinates" and 'WindowStatus" to get emulator window coordinates and window hwnd. I used that handle in window API "SreenToCleint" to get mouse position with respect to emulator window. But i'm unable to translate those co-ordinates into emulator rows and column. I tried many algorithm but unable to get consistent results. I need translate mouse position precisely into PS position. 
Whllap documentation has mentioned "WindowStatus" api to return font sizes for x and y but i'm unable to retrieve any value from Rumba emulator. In order to get fond height and width, I also tried window api 'GetTextMetrcies' but that was not much help either.

Comment: What emulator are you using?

Comment: According to his post - Rumba.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Personal Communications for Windows offers a "Get Mouse Input" DDE function which returns PS position data (row, column) when the user clicks the mouse. There's another DDE function, Set Mouse Intercept Condition, to establish which mouse click(s) (left, right, middle, single, double, etc.) should be intercepted. I don't see a direct way to capture mere mouse movements using the DDE functions, but it might be possible (if you're very careful in your Windows programming) if you generate simulated, rate limited mouse clicks and only when the mouse pointer is moved within the emulator window.

Perhaps Rumba offers similar functions? Rumba evidently has some DDE functions, but I haven't found any DDE function reference for Rumba publicly available online.

One possible caveat is that the DDE functions are 32-bit (and 16-bit functions are also still supported since there's still some 16-bit code running on 32-bit Windows). You can use the 32-bit functions if you're doing 64-bit Windows programming, but of course you'll need to know how to do that if you don't already. Another caveat is that you probably ought to test whatever you're doing for user accessibility, for example with screen reading tools that aid vision impaired users.

Another possible approach is to embed the whole emulator within your own "wrapper" application since that might give you more programming power and control. IBM offers both ActiveX/OLE-style embedding and Java-style embedding (their "Host Access Class Libraries," a.k.a. HACL). Rumba might offer something broadly similar.

And yet another possible approach is to shift the interactions with these applications toward APIs and in favor of brand new, more portable user interfaces, usually Web and mobile interfaces. There are myriad ways to do that. If you still need terminal (3270)-driven automation -- maybe because the application source code is lost or it's otherwise really hard to create useful APIs for it? -- there are a variety of ways to shift that automation into the backend. For example, CICS Transaction Server for z/OS comes with multiple terminal automation technologies as standard included features. Look for references to "3270 bridge" and "FEPI" in IBM's Knowledge Center for CICS to explore that range of choices.